# Azure Search Ranking not working?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have asked this question previously however I didn't get proper reply may be I didn't ask question correctly.

So asking for your help once again

this is my index called "**customers**", below are the fields.

```
Definition = new Index()
   {
      Name = "customers",
      Fields = new[] 
      { 
                    //Customer
       new Field("id",DataType.String) { IsRetrievable=true, IsKey = true },
       new Field("customerId",DataType.String ) { IsRetrievable = true }, 
       new Field("customerName",DataType.String ){ IsSearchable=     true,Sortable     = true, IsRetrievable = true,IsFilterable=true }, 
       new Field("acronym",DataType.String ) { IsSearchable = false, IsRetrievable = true }, 
                    new Field("segment",DataType.String ) { IsRetrievable = true }, 
                    new Field("vertical",DataType.String ) { IsRetrievable = true }, 
                    new Field("country",DataType.String ) { IsRetrievable = true }, 
                    new Field("parentCustomerId",DataType.String ) { IsRetrievable = true }, 
                    //Contacts
                    new Field("contactId",DataType.String){IsRetrievable=true},
                    new Field("contactName",DataType.String){IsSearchable=true,IsRetrievable=true,IsFilterable=true},
                    new Field("recordType",DataType.String){IsRetrievable=true,IsFacetable=true,IsFilterable=true,IsSortable=true},
                    new Field("email",DataType.String){IsRetrievable=true},
                   new Field("websiteURL",DataType.String){IsRetrievable=true }//,IsSearchable=true}
                }
            };
```

Here is my sql view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[XYZ] AS

select  * from
(
select
con.ContactId as id,
con.ContactId as contactID,
cust.Name as **customerName**,
cust.AccountId as customerID,
con.FullName as **contactName**,
con.emailaddress1 as email,
cust.ee_aka as acronym,
Cust.ee_segmentname as segment,
cust.ee_verticalmarketname as vertical,
cust.ee_countryname as country,
'Contacts' as recordType from .......
```

I have uploaded documents for customer and contact information from the view xyz.
I have boosted on fields "**customerName**" and "**contactName**" with **100** and **90** ( I have tried boosting by changing values)

Now when I search from UI web application for "**Johnson**".

Record 1: 
CustomerName: **Johnson & Johnson** 
Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Healthcare | Country: US

Record 2: 
ContactName:Michael Walton 
Customer:**Johnson & Johnson** | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 3: 
ContactName: Henri Vliegen 
Customer:**Johnson and Johnson** | Segment: Ent | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 4: 
ContactName: Henri **Johnson**
Customer:WST | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 5: 
ContactName: bob **Johnson**
Customer:GST | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

So in this way records are displayed its most probably on scores and that too on document "**Johnson & Johnson**" however I want the relevance name to be displayed first like

Record 1: 
CustomerName: **Johnson & Johnson** 
Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Healthcare | Country: US

Record 2: 
ContactName: Henri **Johnson**
Customer:WST | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 3: 
ContactName: bob **Johnson**
Customer:GST | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 4: 
ContactName:Michael Walton 
Customer:**Johnson & Johnson** | Segment: Enterprise | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 5: 
ContactName: Henri Vliegen 
Customer:**Johnson and Johnson** | Segment: Ent | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

so I want to display all the terms starting with "Johnson" first.

Comment: Azure Search team is engaged with the customer for more details. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99437d4d-8d60-4309-87ea-7e73506f6703/azure-search-ranking-issue-?forum=azuresearch